# SQL Server 2008: Case Matrix? Selective Case? Case Association?

Tags: sql-server-2008, case, associative-array

In SQL Server 2008 is there an abbreviated way to match CASE boolean expressions, with the values you'd like to select when the expression is true?

Instead of

```
CASE
    when item='a' then 'Apple'
    when item='b' then 'Ball'
    when item IN ('c','d') then 'Pet'
    when item !='zz' then 'object'
    else 'Bad_Item'
```

I would like something resembling one of the following. These are of course pseudo code, but the idea is to bring the association closer and not to keep writing more when/then pairs

1. Does something like this exist?

   ```
   CASE
       when item ;(=,'a','Apple')
           ;(=,'b','Ball') ;(=,'c' or 'd','Pet')
           ;(!='zz','object') ;'Bad item'
   END
   ```
2. Does something like this exist?

   ```
   CASE
       when item ;= ('a','b','c' or 'd' : 'Apple','Ball','Pet','Object')
                 ;!= ('zz' : 'Object')
                 ;'Bad item'
   END
   ```

Again those were pseudo code, but just wanted to know if there is something faster or simpler or with a listing of all the things to check followed by all the values to select.

Answer (score 2):

There is no shorthand like you describe. You can shorten the code a little bit by using the alternate CASE syntax that @sarwar026 mentioned, but the `<>` line he posted doesn't work. You can't use that form with anything but equality - no inequality, no ranges using between or >=/<=, no IN(), no null checks even.

Comment: Ok. That's good to know. Saves a few testing errors. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

An example of combining the simple and searched `CASE` expressions is:

```
declare @item as VarChar(10) = 'c'

select case @item
  when 'a' then 'Apple' 
  when 'b' then 'Ball'
  else case
    when @item in ( 'c', 'd' ) then 'Pet' 
    when @item != 'zz' then 'object' 
    else 'Bad_Item' end
  end
```

Comment: So by declaring a variable the same type as the data I'll look at I can omit the "when item =" for the parts where equality is needed? That's cool. Is there similar brevity of code for the "IN" cases? Thank you for the help.

Comment: @VISQL As I mentioned, there is no shorthand for IN. Only for direct, non-NULL equality.

Comment: @VISQL - There are two different forms of `CASE` described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).  A _simple_ `CASE` takes an expression and matches it against a series of values in `WHEN`s, like the first part of this answer.  A _searched_ `CASE` goes through a series of `WHEN`s, each having a boolean expression, seeking truth.  One is good for simple lookups, the other for handling a mishmash of assorted tests which can involve many variables in complex relations.

Answer (score 1):

The following works as far I know

```
CASE item
    when 'a' then 'Apple'
    when 'b' then 'Ball'
    when 'c' then 'Pet'
    when 'd' then 'Pet'
    // the next line is not possible, so please discard the next line
    *when  <>'zz' then 'object' // not sure about this syntax*
    else 'Bad_Item'
END
```

Comment: Thanks. I have made a comment in my answer :)

Comment: You can mix and match the two `CASE` styles, i.e. use the simple `CASE` from this answer and place a searched `CASE` in the `ELSE` to handle the more complicated bits.

Comment: So simple case it the shortened one where we only use equality? And thus searched case is the typical "when this='that' then 'this is where its at'